# Does the fallback value get applied to the source for a 2 way binding when there is an error?

Tags: .net, wpf

When there is binding error when sending a value from the source to the target the target receives the fallback value. For a two way binding when an error occurs when the target tries to set a value on the source, does the source also receive the fallback value?

The particular case I have in mind is when a text box is bound to a numeric property of the view model. If the user types a non numeric value in the text box then there there will a conversion exception will occur, in which case I want the model to receive a default value, say 0.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The FallbackValue is used in case:

1. The binding fails in getting the value from the source or
2. The Source returns an UnsetValue.

In either case it does not make sense to return this fallback value to the source, because

1. The binding does not know the source or
2. The converter returns UnsetValue which is not considered valid for target OR source.

If you want a DefaultValue that is also known to your ViewModel, then you should specify it in the ViewModel or Converter.

**EDIT**

When the Value cannot be converted to the source type, the FallbackValue has no effect. To compensate for such a case, I would suggest to create a converter.

Comment: The case I am interested is when the target fails to update the source due to a conversion error, in which case I want the source (a view model) to receive the a default value. Have updated my question to be more clear.